# jquery droppable 'drop' event help

Tags: jquery, droppable, jquery-ui-droppable

What I'm essentially doing is creating a list item on drop. Using the drop event I'm then doing some other fancy stuff with the list. The trouble is, on drop - the item is not created yet.

```
$("#drop").droppable({  
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
      alert($(this).siblings().length);
    }
```

If you have 4 items, it will report 4 even when you just dropped a 5th item in. Is there another event? Or perhaps using a setTimeout which I've used before with some success. I checked the other events but I can't see anything which will trigger after the element is dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just access the draggable element, you use ui.draggable.

If you need to update the list and such, it's likely that you need to use setTimeout.